# string.ascii_letters + string.digits: How do I define how many letters and numbers I want?

Tags: python

```
import secrets
import string

st = ''
abc = string.ascii_letters
digits = string.digits

generate = secrets.choice(digits + abc)
password = st.join(generate)
print(password)
```

For loop is not workable because I want to get characters from `abc` and digits too, and I want to get the output mixed (`abc` and `digits`).

It must be like this: `nB5nP9`

It is simple in the `random` module:

```
random.choices(variable, k=5)
```

How does it look like in `secrets`?

Comment: `secrets.choice` returns one random element. If you want more elements, call it repeatedly. I'm not sure why you think you can't use a loop for that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "For loop is not workable", using a for loop (or loop comprehension, in the below case) will still mix alphanumeric characters together:

```py
length = 15

password = "".join(secrets.choice(digits + abc) for _ in range(length))

print(password)
```

*Update: My best guess is that you tried to do something similar to the above, but only got a password with alphabet characters (no numbers). This is an unfortunate coincidence- `digits + abc` is 62 characters in length, and 10 of them are numbers. With a bit of math (`1 - (1 - 10 / 62) ** 5 = 0.58`), we can say that there is a ~60% chance that your test appeared invalid, and only returned alphabet characters.*

Comment: I already did. And how can I define how many numbers and letters I want in password?

Comment: The length? By changing the `length` variable.